# Why does string.search work for some strings and not others?

Tags: javascript, string, search

In the following code, the first search works correctly but the second returns an error:
TypeError: Result of expression 'str.search' [] is not a function.
This is surprising as I was expecting the result to be a numerical value, not a function. I didn't see other questions with the same error, so am hoping this is an obvious beginner error.

```
function loadT() {
  var pos;
  var str;

  str=window.name;
  pos= str.search(" ");
  if (pos > -1) {
    window.name = str.slice(0,pos);
  }

  str=window.location;
  pos= str.search("#");
  if (pos > -1) {
    sender = str.slice(pos+1);
  }
 }
```

Comment: Tag language, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `window.location` is not a string, but on Object, you should cast it:

```
str = "" + window.location;
```